# Calculate total price based on data-price and visible div?

Tags: jquery, hidden-field

I am stuck with hide/show a div and calculating a total price. Let's say i have a divA and divB. Now when div A is visible two divs are visible with menu options and data-price attributes. It works when i hardcode the var $elements, but when divB is visible i like the var $elements to read only divB1, see code

```
var $elements = $('#divA1, #divA2');
    var $elements = $('#divB1');
    $elements.on('change', function() {
         var $selected = $elements.children(":selected");
         var sum = 0;

         $selected.each(function() {
             sum += $(this).data('price');
         });

         $('#total_price').html('€'+sum);
    });
```

Comment: will you please add fiddle link for better understanding of your problem

Answer (score 0):

Your mistake is in line2, you are redeclaring variable $elements,

```
var $elements = $('#divA1, #divA2');
var $elements_b = $('#divB1');
if ($elements_b.length != 0) {
    $elements = $elements_b;
}
$elements.on('change', function () {
    var $selected = $elements.children(":selected");
    var sum = 0;

    $selected.each(function () {
        sum += $(this).data('price');
    });

    $('#total_price').html('€' + sum);
});
```

Comment: @Laximikant yes i am aware of that. I have the second one outcommented in my code but i want to use one of the $elements variable based on a menu option selection something like
`if (!$('#optionsA').is(":hidden")) {
        $elements = $('#divA1, #divA2');
    }
    if (!$('#optionsB').is(":hidden")) {
        $elements = $('#divB1');
    }` and the visibility is set by an option menu and is check onready by `$('#formstep2').find("select[data-toggle='#stdOptions']").on('change', function() {
        
        var $target = $($(this).find('option:selected').attr('data-toggle')); `